# Why can't I use an anonymous function for returning a color value?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to pass an anonymous function that returns a **Color** to the **color:** argument of the **Container()** constructor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmdgL.png

I'm trying to create a container with a random color. Because the value of the random generator will change with every redraw, I can easily spot which parts of my application are being rerendered.

I'm aware that I can also use the overlays in the debugger for this, but I'm more interested in why this isn't working than in how to achieve that goal.

I've tried

```dart
Container(
  color: () {
    Random r = Random();
    return Color.fromRGBO(
        r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), 1.0);
  }
)
```

and

```dart
Container(
  color: (Random r = Random()) => Color.fromRGBO(
        r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), 1.0),
)
```

I thought this would be the ideal place to use anonymous functions, but it isn't? What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: "Anonymous function that returns a Color". Yeah, but a function only returns when invoked. The flutter runtime expects a color but you give it a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an anonymous function, you will have to invoke it:

```
Container(
  color: (() {
    Random r = Random();
    return Color.fromRGBO(
        r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), 1.0);
  })()
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I always thought that a function returning a value is the same as a value. Is that only true for functions in arrow notation?

Comment: @HorstKugel That is *never* the case. When you pass callbacks, e.g. `onPressed`, you are passing the function as a [`Function`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Function-class.html) (which is a regular object) that has a `call` method which can be invoked by `()` or `.call()`.